# Is there a way to filter out syn request packets using c#?

Tags: c#, packet-capture, winpcap, pcap.net, sharppcap

I am new to c# so please bear with me. I am trying to find some answers on the net but I can't seem to do so. I am working on a C# packet capture application that captures the number of SYN requests that the user gets. Is there a way for me to filter out all of the SYN requests using Pcap.net or sharppcap?

I have tried looking at the wiki and documentations for both libraries but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either filter the packets [using BerkeleyPacketFilter](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Filtering-the-traffic) or you could post filter the packets after you capture them.